# How to solve delay calculations, namely propagation delay and transmition delay (Clarify the formula)

Tags: statistics, network

I have a big exam coming up in January and a small portion of it is on Delay calculations. My tutors are not very helpful when it comes to this so I was wondering if I could get some help with[enter image description here][1] understanding the maths (I do not have a strong mathematical background).

[1] Here is the question w/ answers: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kjWK.png

Comment: What is the question?  How much of the discussion do you understand?  What *specifically* do you not understand?

Comment: Hi, I have linked the question and answer in the description. I just don't understand how I reach that answer, I am not familiar with the symbols/variables in the question - I guess I want a step by step guide to solve such a formula

Comment: I don't see any symbols that aren't explained in the discussion.  I don't see what anyone could do in a forum like this except repeat the discussion you've posted, which obviously wouldn't help you.  You surely understand some of this, don't you?  For example, part a) says it takes $2m/s$ seconds to travel $2m$ meters at a rate of $s$ meters per second.  You understand that, right?  What about part b)?

Comment: Okay Im starting to realize this may be simpler than I thought. Okay so for B why is it "2L" rather than just "L" and the same for "2M" rather than just "M" (Sorry Im just asking this so I can confirm my understanding)

Comment: That's fine.  That's the kind of question you *should* be asking.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The packet is placed on the transmission line twice, once by each host (remember, it's store-and-forward).  Each time it takes $L/R$ seconds.  ($L-$bit packet, host is $R$ bits per second.) As to the $2m$ meters, it's given in the first part of the problem that both $a$ and $b$ are equal to $m$.